# A question about the pull-back and proper pushforward functors (convolution product of perverse sheaves) on $SL(2,\mathbb C)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, sheaf-cohomology

Let $G = SL(2,\mathbb C)$, which is an algebraic group of type $A_1$ over $\mathbb C$. Let $B$ be a Borel subgroup of $G$. Let $X =G/B$. Then $X \cong \mathbb P^1$ and it has a stratification $X = X_{e} \sqcup X_{s}$, where $X_e = $pt and $X_s \cong \mathbb A_1$. Let $j_s: X_s \hookrightarrow X$ be the inclusion. In the following, for any space $Y$, $\underline{\mathbb C}_Y$ denotes the constant sheaf on $Y$ with value $\mathbb C$.

I have to show

> $j_{s!}\underline{\mathbb C}_{X_s}*\underline{\mathbb C}_{\mathbb P^1} = \underline{\mathbb C}_{\mathbb P^1}[-2]$.

Already know: for $a: X \rightarrow $pt, $j_{s!}\underline{\mathbb C}_{X_s}*\underline{\mathbb C}_{\mathbb P^1} = a^*a_!j_{s!}\underline{\mathbb C}_{X_s}$.
But what I cannot go through is

1. $a_!j_{s!}\underline{\mathbb C}_{X_s} = \underline{\mathbb C}_{\text{pt}}[-2] = H_c^{\bullet}(\mathbb A^1)$.
2. $a^*(\underline{\mathbb C}_{\text{pt}}[-2])$ (or $a^*(H_c^{\bullet}(\mathbb A^1))$) $=\underline{\mathbb C}_{\mathbb P^1}[-2]$.

Would anyone please explain me the equations, or give another proof, other than using the isomorphism $K(D^b_B(X)) \cong H_{q=-1}$, where $K(D^b_B(X))$ is the Grothendieck group of $D^b_B(X)$ with the convolution product and $H_{q=-1}$ is the Hecke algebra specializing at $q =-1$?

For the definition of convolution product, please read [Perverse sheaves on affine Grassmannians and Langlands duality](http://scholarworks.umass.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1730&context=math_faculty_pubs) or other references.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand what is troubling you. You want to prove that the cohomology with compact  of $\mathbb{A}^1$ is just $\mathbb{C}$ in degree 2, and that the pull-back of a constant sheaf is a constant sheaf ? Isn't it obvious ?

Comment: @user113969 Thank you very much for the comment. So what about the first equation $a_!j_{s!}\underline{\mathbb C}_{X_s} = \underline{\mathbb C}_{\text{pt}}[-2]$? In fact, what you have mentioned , together with the first equation, are truly what troubling me. We have to take a course on perverse sheaves but my knowledge on algebraic geometry is far from being systematic. Thanks again.

Comment: Well this is the cohomology with compact support of $\mathbb{A}^1$. In fact for any $X$, $f_!\mathbb{C}_X$ is the complex computing the cohomology with compact support of $X$ (here $f:X\rightarrow pt$ is the projection onto a point. In your case $a_!{j_s}_!\mathbb{C}=(aj_s)_!\mathbb{C}$ with $aj_s:X_s\rightarrow pt$ and $X_s\simeq\mathbb{A}^1$. So this is the cohomology with compact support of $\mathbb{A}^1$. As you probably know it (or use Poincaré duality for a quick proof), it is concentrated in degree 2, and thus, this complex is $\mathbb{C}[-2]$.

Comment: @user113969 I get it now. Thanks a lot!